# Is every sufficient condition also a necessary condition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been studying calculus and I understand what sufficient and necessary conditions are, but is it true that every sufficient condition is also a necessary one?

For example:

Let $\sum{a_n}$ be a convergent series. If the series is convergent, then $a_n\to 0$. From this we can conclude that necessary condition for series convergence is that $a_n$ must be a zero sequence. A sufficient condition for series convergence is that its partial sum must also converge. My question is, is this condition also necessary? Are there convergent series whose partial sum isn't convergent?

Comment: "is it true that every sufficient condition is also a necessary one?" NO.

Comment: What Mauro said. Think of it this way: sufficient means "if". Necessary means "only if"

Comment: See [Differentiability and continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity) : "In particular, any differentiable function must be continuous at every point in its domain. The converse does not hold: a continuous function need not be differentiable."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but this means that continuity is a necessary condition for a function to be differentiable. My question was about sufficient condition

Comment: If A, then B reads "A is a **sufficient** condition for B" and also "B is a **necessary** condition for A".

Comment: So, *differentiability* is **sufficient** for *continuity* and *continuity* is **necessary** for *differentiability*.

Comment: @Vuk Differentiability is a sufficient condition for continuity (since all differentiable functions are continuous) but it is not a necessary condition (since there are continuous funcitons that are not differentiable).

Comment: @in_mathematica_we_trust thanks, I understand now, but is it possible for a sufficient condition to sometimes also be a necessary one? Like in my example above

Comment: Obviously yes : a number is *even* iff it is not *odd*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks!

Comment: In general, a condition can be necessary but not sufficient; sufficient but not necessary; necessary and sufficient; or neither sufficient nor necessary for a particular result. It just depends on which condition and which result you are looking at.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by your example, however. Convergence of the partials sums is usually taken as the _definition_ of a convergent series (e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvergentSeries.html). When we are making a definition such as, "If a widget is frazzled then it is a gadget," then _by definition_ the condition "widget is frazzled" is sufficient (because the definition says when the condition is satisfied you have a gadget) and necessary (because the only way we can say something is a gadget is by applying the definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can have all kinds of conditions.
For example, consider the following candidates to be the "condition" that an integer $n$ is even:

*Sufficient but not necessary:* $n$ is divisible by $4.$

*Necessary but not sufficient:* $n \neq 1.$

*Necessary and sufficient:* The last digit of the decimal representation of $n$ is $0, 2, 4, 6,$ or $8.$

*Neither necessary nor sufficient:* $n$ is divisible by $3.$

---

Your example, however, is not just any mathematical statement.
We usually *define* a convergent series by saying something like this:

> The infinite series $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent if its sequence of partial sums converges.

(See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvergentSeries.html) for example.)

Because this is a definition, *by definition* the condition "partial sums converge" is sufficient (the definition literally says so), and it is also necessary, because *by definition* that property, and not any other possible property, is what makes a series convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a *proper* subset of $B$ and let $B$ be a *proper* subset of $C$.

Then $x\in A$ is sufficient (but not necessary) for $x\in B$ and $x\in C$ is necessary (but not sufficient) for $x\in B$.

It is handsome to keep this picture/Venn diagram in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The two qualifiers are used because they are independent.

For $x>1$, $x>0$ is necessary but not sufficient.

For $x>1$, $x>2$ is sufficient but not necessary.

For $x>1$, $y>1$ is neither necessary nor sufficient.

For $x>1$, $x-1>0$ is both necessary and sufficient.