# Translate "A is not necessary for B" in math expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I tried to to solve this but what I found is

```
A is not necessary for B
```

> I could be wrong

```
= not(A is necessary for B)
= not(not(B) or A)
= not(A) and B
```

but it doesn't make sense.
Let's take an example:

```
A = understand things
B = argue about things
A is not necessary to B = not(A) and B
```

so

> Understand things is not necessary to argue about things = Not understand things and argue about things

should be the same thing.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: $A$ does not imply $B$?

Comment: "A is not necessary for B" means that B could be true even when A is false. So $B \nRightarrow A$

Comment: @stuartstevenson That states that $A$ is not *sufficient* for $B$. The correct answer is: $B$ does not imply $A$. Also have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942178/is-every-sufficient-condition-also-a-necessary-condition/2942186#2942186).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that instead of negating $B \to A$, you probably intend a meaning that is better expressed by negating $\forall x.(B \to A)$

Answer (score 4):

"$A$ necessary for $B$" is actually "$B$ implies $A$"

So "$A$ not necessary for $B$" is actually "$B$ does not imply $A$"

In mathematical notation:$$\neg[B\implies A]\text{ or equivalently }\neg A\wedge B$$

This states that $B$ can be true while at the same time $A$ is not true (so no necessity for $A$ to be true in order to achieve that $A$ is true).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that, strictly speaking, the statement should be written in predicate logic, rather than propositional logic. In which case it would be $\neg[\forall x\in B, x\in A]$, or some other variation on this.

Comment: "B implies A" is equivalent with "not(B) or A". This is mentioned in the question (" not(A is necessary for B) = not(not(B) or A)"). I do not see how you answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

When you interpret "is necessary" as "is implied by" then indeed we have "$A$ is not neccessary for $B$" exactly where "not $A$ yet $B$".

Check the truth table: $$\begin{array}{l:l|cc}A & B & A\gets B\\\hline \top & \top & \top  \\ \top & \bot & \top \\ \bot & \top & \bot &\star \\\bot& \bot & \top \end{array}$$

---

The issue is you are interpreting "is not necessary" as "is *maybe* not implied by"; which requires modal logic quantifiers.

$$\neg\Box(B\to A)\equiv \Diamond(B\land\lnot A)$$